# html2canvas resulting image very different from DOM

Tags: html2canvas

I am having issues with html2canvas not rendering the node exactly how it is displayed. I know it has limited support for CSS properties and we are using the `transform` property here.  Does anyone know more precisely how to debug this, or if this is a limitation of the library?

Actual node look:
[image]

Image generated by html2canvas:
[image]

This is the html2canvas code:

```
const takeScreenshot = async () => {
  const node = document.getElementById("screenshot-area");
  if (node == null) return;

  const canvas = await html2canvas(node, {
    useCORS: true,
    windowHeight: 550,
    height: 430,
    backgroundColor: "#141627",
  });

  const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = "screenshot.png";
  link.href = image;
  link.click();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the information available on the page.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas

...Sorry